# Pass Julia arguments to be executed in REPL?

Tags: bash, julia, alias, read-eval-print-loop

I very (very!) often do this routine in my daily work:

```
$ j7 # (alias for Julia version 1.7)
julia>
julia> ] activate .
(or similarly) (@v1.8) pkg> activate . 
Activating project at `~/MyMWE_WorkingPath`
julia> using Revise ; using RRSP # RRSP is my working module
```

I would like to have an alias for doing this routine quicker and easilier. I do it at the very least ten times a week and will do it for months more.

Ideally, I would do something like, j7RRSP which is an alias for:

```
alias j7RRSP='julia > ]activate . ; using Revise ; using RRSP'
```

This is incorrect and I don't know how to do it well!
I know alias for executing julia files are possible :

```
alias j7jl='julia somefiles.jl'
```

In my case, I am activating a project then using two packages, Revise, which is standard, then RRSP that I created.

Comment: Quick answer: you are looking to customize your `startup.jl` file and also for the `--project` option for julia command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is using a function that works exactly like an alias, but with a much saner syntax and capabilities:

```bash
j7RRSP() {
  julia --project=. -e "using Revise, RRSP" -i "$@"
}
```

As a one-line:

```bash
j7RRSP(){ julia --project=. -e "using Revise, RRSP" -i "$@";}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one solution:

```
alias j7RRSP='julia --project=. -e "using Revise, RRSP" -i'
```

Flags:

- `--project=.`: start with the project in the current directory directly instead of using `]activate .`,
- `-e "..."`: evaluate the code `...`,
- `-i`: ask for an interactive session, this is needed since otherwise, due to combining with `-e`, the process exits after evaluating the code.